# One attribute category defines colour, another attribute category defines shape

Tags: qgis, symbology, point

I want to set the point colour to be defined by one attribute (Lithology), and the shape to be defined by another attribute (Qualifier). For example,

Lithology (RH) = Yellow, Qualifier (CR) = Square, resulting marker is a yellow square.

Lithology (AN) = Blue, Qualifier (BX) = Triangle, resulting marker is a blue triangle.

Lithology (RH) = Yellow, Qualifier (BX) = Triangle, resulting marker is a yellow triangle.

13 different lithologies, and 15 different qualifiers exist, and I have ~500 points.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in Qgis by using "rule based" symbology with two levels of settings.

To safe you a bit of work you go to "symbology" - "categories" first and classify your data on the column qualifier that defines your shapes. But don´t set any shapes yet, its just a work in progress step and will be dismissed in the end.

Then you go to "rule based". You should see rules like "qualifier" = 'BX'

You then right click one of the rules and choose "refine activ rule" - "add categories" and then you classify the colors you want to have by the column Lithology.

This is the first rule that is ready and should show you the colors you want to have for one single shape. Then you right click this rule and copy - paste it for your different shapes. You then copy the rule text from your earlier rules into the ones you copied and where you set now the shapes. The first set of rules you can delete, they where just for copying the rule-text. Through the copies of the rules you have now the same color definitions for each shape and it should end in the symbology hierarchy you want with acceptable effort.