# QGIS categorise shapes on one attribute and format symbology based on different attribute

Tags: qgis, symbology

Using QGIS 3.30.2
I have a polygon shapefile with 20 shapes in it.
Using symbology ---> categorized. I have 20 different shapes categorized based on Attribute A which has 20 variables (so that I can turn them on and off as needed). But instead of having 20 different colored shapes I want to color each shape based on Attribute B which has only 5 variables.

Comment: just to clarify you want to still have your 20 different category from attribute A but these 20 category should share 5 color based on attribute B (so several category A have the same color) . If yes this may have the answer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197988/one-attribute-category-defines-colour-another-attribute-category-defines-shape/197991#197991

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the attribute in the symbology tab in the layer's property then click on classify, see screenshot below:

[image]